# Get value from url(..) if it does not contain Data URI — regex

Tags: javascript, css, regex

My question is about `url(..)` in CSS.

I have string like `url('blah-blah.jpg')`. So I've tried to get URI value from it and I've got it correctly (in JavaScript) using this regex:

```
/url\(\s*['"]?(.*?)['"]?\s*\)/g;
```

But if `url` contains Data URI I don't want to get it. How should I modify my regex for it? I think I should add something like negative lookahead section, but I can't do it correctly.

Examples of mismatching:

```
url(data:image/gif;base64,R...)
url("data:image/png;base64,Ga..")
```

Examples of matching:

```
url(http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico)
url("http://wikipedia.org/jimmy.png")
```

Note: I want to get exactly regex solution. I know that in JS I can use other tools for the problem, but I need a regex. Thanks!

Comment: What's an example of what you do NOT want to match?

Comment: @Marc I've added examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
url\(\s*['"]?(?!['"]?data:)(.*?)['"]?\s*\)
```

Comment: Good catch on the quote marks in the look ahead. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try using this negative lookahead in the middle of your regex:

```
((?!['"]?data:).*?)
```

### Example:

```js
var reg = /url\(\s*['"]?((?!['"]?data:).*?)['"]?\s*\)/g;

// Matches:
console.log('url(http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico)'.match(reg));
console.log('url("http://wikipedia.org/jimmy.png")'.match(reg));

// Unmatched:
console.log('url(data:image/gif;base64,R...)'.match(reg));
console.log('url("data:image/gif;base64,R...")'.match(reg));
```

### [RegExplained](http://tinyurl.com/hay6atc):

[image: regex graph]

Comment: You have pics, but answer by @dhinus is more correctly. But thank you too!

Comment: @IgorAdamenko Just curious, in what way is it more-correct?

Comment: His solution works on `url("data:image/gif;base64,R...")` too, i. e. when value of `url` in quotes.

Comment: @IgorAdamenko Good call, I'll fix the bug for future readers.